# elasticsearch query from different field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am pretty new to elasticsearch query. my query will be like 
    `red dresses` or `red sleeveless` in my elasticsearch  a sample document structure is as shown below:

INDEX NAME="cloths", TYPE_NAME="dresses"

```
"_source": {
      "product_filter": {
         "brand": "abc",
         "price": 100,
         "colour": "red",
         "sleeve": "sleeveless"
     }
}
```

both the term in query has to be matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Query String](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-query-string-query) query will be useful here:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "red sleeveless",
            "default_operator": "AND"
        }
    }
}
```